# why the output of fmt.Println() is not what I need

Tags: go

I am new to Golang, and I am confused by the output order of `fmt.println()`, here is my code

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func pow(x, n, lim float64) float64 {
    if v := math.Pow(x, n); v < lim {
        return v
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%g >= %g\n", v, lim)
    }
    return lim
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(
        pow(3, 2, 10),
        pow(3, 3, 20),
    )
    //fmt.Println(pow(3, 2, 10))
    //fmt.Println(pow(3, 3, 20))
}
```

The output is

```
27 >= 20
9 20
```

And what I want is

```
9
27 >= 20
20
```

And add more print statement in `pow()`:

```golang
func pow(x, n, lim float64) float64 {
    if v := math.Pow(x, n); v < lim {
        fmt.Println("___1___")
        return v
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%g >= %g\n", v, lim)
    }
    fmt.Println("___2___")
    return lim
}
```

the output is

```
___1___
27 >= 20
___2___
9 20
```

Why the output is that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Order of evaluation](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Order_of_evaluation):

> At package level, initialization dependencies determine the evaluation
>   order of individual initialization expressions in variable
>   declarations. Otherwise, when evaluating the operands of an
>   expression, assignment, or return statement, all function calls,
>   method calls, and communication operations are evaluated in lexical
>   left-to-right order.
>
> For example, in the (function-local) assignment
>
> ```
> y[f()], ok = g(h(), i()+x[j()], <-c), k()
> ```
>
> the function calls and communication happen in the order f(), h(),
>   i(), j(), <-c, g(), and k(). However, the order of those events
>   compared to the evaluation and indexing of x and the evaluation of y
>   is not specified.
>
> ```
> a := 1
> f := func() int { a++; return a }
> x := []int{a, f()}            // x may be [1, 2] or [2, 2]: evaluation order between a and f() is not specified
> m := map[int]int{a: 1, a: 2}  // m may be {2: 1} or {2: 2}: evaluation order between the two map assignments is not specified
> n := map[int]int{a: f()}      // n may be {2: 3} or {3: 3}: evaluation order between the key and the value is not specified
> ```
>
> At package level, initialization dependencies override the
>   left-to-right rule for individual initialization expressions, but not
>   for operands within each expression:
>
> ```
> var a, b, c = f() + v(), g(), sqr(u()) + v()
>
> func f() int        { return c }
> func g() int        { return a }
> func sqr(x int) int { return x*x }
>
> // functions u and v are independent of all other variables and functions
> ```
>
> The function calls happen in the order u(), sqr(), v(), f(), v(), and
>   g().
>
> Floating-point operations within a single expression are evaluated
>   according to the associativity of the operators. Explicit parentheses
>   affect the evaluation by overriding the default associativity. In the
>   expression x + (y + z) the addition y + z is performed before adding
>   x.

---

If you need:

```
9
27 >= 20
20
```

First call `pow(3, 2, 10)` and `Print` the result, like this working sample code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"
import "math"

func pow(x, n, lim float64) float64 {
    if v := math.Pow(x, n); v < lim {
        return v
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%g >= %g\n", v, lim)
    }
    return lim
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(pow(3, 2, 10))
    fmt.Println()

    fmt.Println(pow(3, 3, 20))
}
```

output:

```
9

27 >= 20
20
```

---

See the order of function calls in this working sample code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func pow(n float64) float64 {
    fmt.Println("order:", n)
    return n
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(pow(1), pow(2), pow(3))
}
```

output:

```
order: 1
order: 2
order: 3
1 2 3
```

---

And:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func pow(n int) int {
    fmt.Println("order:", n)
    return n
}

func main() {
    a, b, c := pow(1), pow(2), pow(3)
    fmt.Println("Order 4")
    fmt.Println(a, b, c)
}
```

output:

```
order: 1
order: 2
order: 3
Order 4
1 2 3
```

---

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func pow(n int) int {
    fmt.Println("order:", n)
    return n
}

func main() {
    a := pow(1)
    b := pow(2)
    c := pow(3)
    fmt.Println("Order 4")
    fmt.Println(a, b, c)
}
```

output:

```
order: 1
order: 2
order: 3
Order 4
1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of the order of the function calls. When a function is called, all of its arguments are evaluated before the actual function call.

So here, in the below call:

```
fmt.Println(
    pow(3, 2, 10),
    pow(3, 3, 20),
)
```

both `pow(3, 2, 10)` and `pow(3, 3, 20)` are evaluated (called) before the call to `println` is made. Thus, the output of `printf` (which is called in turn by the second call to `pow(3, 3, 20)`) appears before the `println` outputs the return values from `pow`.